# Curl of a vector field

Tags: differentiation, vector-fields

What is the physical interpretation of curl of a vector field? Just as divergence implies flux through a surface.

I mean if $\vec A$ is a vector field, what does $\left(\nabla \times \vec A \right)$ indicate?

Any mathematical help is welcome.

NOTE: I request the reader if he\she likes the question, please vote to reopen it. I think the question needs new answers.

Comment: A good answer to this question really ought to give a diagram illustrating that curl has to do with the swirly-ness of the vector field.

Comment: @Rob Jeffries: It is not the case whether the question is good or not but rather it was closed as the scope of the query was too broad to be answerable. Moreover this type of question could be easily answered by quick googling. If there is any problem, then OP could ask that but the present scenario of this question is really too broad.

Comment: @user36790 Make your mind up. It is either too broad or it could easily be answered by quick googling. Which?

Comment: @Rob Jeffries: Both; there are lots & lots of sites that provide the interpretation of curl. It would thus become a trivial question; we would not answer a question that can be googlable, would you? However, if OP faces problem conceiving the explanation, then he can ask here & would definitely be helped. As that of being broad, actually he asks for a whole description of _curl_: its definition, interpretation, illustrations etc; so he wants a wikipedia-article on it...

Comment: ...now that is what is meant to be _broad_. But as you can see now, sir, he has quite narrowed his query to how the mathematical equation is connected to rotation. This can be a competent question as per SE standards now(However, I'm still dubious as to how it is related to physics in anyway; it would be much beneficial for him to ask his new query at Math SE).

Comment: Dear @Aniket, could you please ask it as a separate question on this site or at Math SE? I would love to write an answer on this but don't know whether it would be reopened or not & if it happens also, there can be a great delay. So, could you freshly ask a new question on your latest query?

Comment: @user36790 If I ask this as a separate question on this site, are you sure it won't be flagged duplicate and hence closed?

Comment: @Aniket: I don't know but see, the question that you previously asked here was quite different from what you are asking now; the banner is same but the body is different. So, it would rather be better to rollback this question to the old query & better ask your latest query as a new question; it would not be closed then as _duplicate_ however I'm fearing since it doesn't deal with any concept of physics, it could be closed as _off-topic_ . So, my advice is, ask a new question but not here, rather at Math SE.

Comment: @user36790 all right with your suggestion. But one question I can't resist to ask: Why do you think vectors are not related to physics (off-topic)? As much as I know, every undergraduate course in physics involves rigorous study of vector calculus.

Comment: @user36790 On the contrary. *Now* the question can easily be answered by google and is duplicated on Physics SE. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/211773/significance-of-curl-nabla-times-boldsymbolv?lq=1

Comment: @Aniket: Mathematics is a tool & we rigorously _use_ it in physics but that doesn't make it a part of _physics_.

Comment: @Rob Jeffries: Yes, but partly; the query that how it is related to rotation(_infinitesimal circulation_) is a different query.

Comment: I've edited a comment. Let Me Google That For You does not make up any part of "nice" interaction within the scope of the network-wide "Be nice." policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl is a measure of the rate at which a(n infinitesimally small) region of fluid rotates about its own centre.   You might measure it by inserting a (very) small paddlewheel in the fluid - the speed at which it rotates is the curl.   For example, on a fairground Ferris wheel, the big wheel rotates (non-zero curl) the gondolas gyrate (zero curl).   Swirl some beer in a glass;  the beer rotates (non-zero curl), the glass gyrates (zero curl).

BTW, 'divergence' is flux over a closed curve/surface.   If the curve/surface doesn't enclose a source or sink, and the fluid is incompressible, the divergence is zero.   Essentially 'what goes in, comes out'

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by gyration and why it is zero curl?

Comment: @aniket:  gyration is when something follows a circular path but doesn't rotate about its own centre ergo zero curl.   The gondolas of the Ferris wheel are possibly the most obvious example.

Answer (score 0):

Curl is circulation per unit area just like divergence is net flux per unit volume.

So any time you care about circulation per area then there you go.

Wind farm, vector potentials, magnetic fields, currents.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a 2 dimensional vector field which represents the velocity in a fluid. Let us examine two different cases and calculate the curl of the velocity vector.

First, suppose the vector field $\vec{v}$ is given by 
$$
\vec{v}(x,y,z) = (y,-x,0).
$$
If you plot this, we realize that it represents a fluid rotating in the clockwise direction. The curl is given by:
$$
\nabla \times \vec{v} = \left [\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(-x) -\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(y)  \right ]\hat{z} = -2\hat{z}
$$
So the curl gives two times the angular speed at the point. Of course, the field could be much more complex, and its curl would be different in different points of the surface.

Now, let us consider a field given by:
$$
\vec{v}(x,y,z) = (x,y,0).
$$
Again, if you plot this you will see that it describes a fluid which is flowing radially from the origin. There is no rotation in this case, because the fluid is just flowing away. Let us compute the curl of the vector field:
$$
\nabla \times \vec{v} = \left [\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x) -\frac{\partial}{\partial y} (y) \right ]\hat{z} = 0.
$$
So the curl vanishes when the fluid is nonrotational.

The take-home message from these two examples is that curl is related to rotation in fluids.

Comment: Only rotations of fluids? Nothing else?