# Physical significance of divergence

Tags: differentiation, vector-fields

In my textbook 
They considered a parallelopiped $ABCDEFGH$ with sides $dx,dy,dz$ parallel to $x,y,z$ axis respectively

- $\vec V$ represents the vector velocity of the fluid at the centre $P$ of [image: i added this pic because i don't know how to draw that cordinate systema and parallelopiped right there,i'm learning that thing..it will be very helpfull if you tell me more about this,how it works.]f the volume (parallelopiped) with components $V_x,V_y,V_z$ along three axis
- the fluid flows in or out through the all six faces.
- let us consider the fluid flow through the two opposite faces 1 and 2 of the volume element each being normal to x-axis and has area=dydz
- **The value of the x component of $\vec V$ at the centre of the face 1 and 2 will be different from $V_x$ at the at the centre $P$.**
- **$\frac {\partial V_x}{\partial x}$ is the rate of change of $V_x$ along x-axis, then the change in value of $V_x$ in going from $P$ to the centre of vertical faces 1 or 2 = $\frac{\partial V_xdx}{\partial x2}$**
- **the value of x-component of the velocity $\vec V$ at the centre of face 
  1 = $V_x-\frac{1}{2}\frac {\partial V_x}{x}dx$**

---

Now my problem is

- "The value of the $x$ component of $\vec V$ at the centre of the face 1 and 2 will be different from $V_x$ at the at the centre $P$" 
  *Why?*
- $\frac {\partial V_x}{\partial x}$ is the rate of change of $V_x$ along $x$-axis, then the change in value of $V_x$ in going from $P$ to the centre of vertical faces 1 or 2 = $\frac{\partial V_xdx}{\partial x2}$
- $\frac {\partial V_x}{\partial x}$ is the rate of change of $V$ along x-axis because here water is flowing in all directions and we are concerned with the $x$ axis only, okay. But, change in the value of $V_x$ in going from $p$ to the centre of vertical faces of 1 or 2 = $$\frac{\partial V_xdx}{\partial x2}$$ but *how and why*. Please explain
- the value of $x$-component of the velocity $\vec V$ at the centre of face 
  1 = $V_x-\frac{1}{2}\frac {\partial V_x}{x}dx$

*How and why* please explain.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/264509/2451 and links therein.

Comment: 1. Because $v_x$ changes with $x$.

Comment: @RobJeffries what??

Comment: @Qmechanici checked out that...i didn't get my answer ..that is not a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

**“The value of the  component of $\vec{V}$ at the centre of the face 1 and 2 will be different from $_x$ at the centre .”**

*“The $x$ component of* $\vec{V}$” And “$V_x$” are the same thing. This just says $V_x$ is a function, so it’s value changes because $x$ changed going from center to a face. (See note about their bad terminology at the bottom of this.)

---

Unless otherwise specified, $\vec{V}$, and $V_x$ (the $x$-component of $V$), are specified at the point being considered, point P. Let’s call that point (a,b,c).

The center of face I is at ($a - \frac{dx}{2}$, b, c), and center of II is at ($a + \frac{dx}{2}$, b, c). If y =b and z=c don’t change, then on that line from center of I... to P... to center of II, everything is only a function of x.

Because dx is small, we can assume the change in $V_x$ is just the change in $x$ times $\frac{\partial V_x}{\partial x}$.  But notice that the change in $x$ is $\frac{d x}{2}$.

(That’s what $\frac{\partial V_x}{\partial x}$ means: how much $V_x$ changes per change in $x$)

---

**The value of x-component of the velocity ⃗ at the centre of face 1** $= V_x- \left( \frac{\partial V_x}{\partial x}\right)~\left( \frac{dx}{2}\right)$ **How? Why?**

Change in $V_x$ going from P to face I

= Change in $V_x$ from $x=a$ to $x=a - \frac{dx}{2}$

= Change in $V_x$ from decreasing x by $ \frac{dx}{2}$

$=~ \left( \frac{\partial V_x}{\partial x}\right)~\left(\Delta x\right)=~ \left( \frac{\partial V_x}{\partial x}\right)~\left(- \frac{dx}{2}\right) $ $$\implies V_{x~\text{(face-}I)}= V_{x~(P)}- \left( \frac{\partial V_x}{\partial x}\right)~\left( \frac{dx}{2}\right)$$

Note, they seem at times to be implying “When I say $V_x$, Im talking about the x-component of $V$, **at point P**, but when I say ‘the $x$ component of V’ that could be referring to anywhere”. Which is dumb.

Comment: Use `\left(content\right)` instead of `(content)` in order to adjust their height to that of the content. Similarly for `\left(content\right)`.

Comment: @Frobenius Was wondering exactly that. But Im missing something about what you wrote, if we could do an example “( \frac{\partial V_x}{\partial x} ) ” .. you are talking about parenthesis right?

Comment: Ok I see thanks

Comment: I edit some parentheses in your question. There are also bigger symbols for example `\bigl(content\bigr),\biggl(content\biggr),\Bigl(content\Bigr)`.

Comment: @Frobenius Thanks much 

Comment: Take a look at this norm symbols I like very much
$$
\Vert \dfrac{\partial \mathbf A}{\partial x}\Vert
$$
$$
\left\Vert \dfrac{\partial \mathbf A}{\partial x}\right\Vert
$$
The bad one on the top uses `\Vert.....\Vert` while the good one in the bottom uses `\left\Vert.....\right\Vert`. I expect amazing answers by your side in the future and I would like to be well-formatted.

Comment: @Frobenius Yeah that helps. Something about the directional asymmetry  of the parens ) (  symbols made the method seem inconsistently applied but I see was not.

Answer (score 0):

The velocity $V$ is actually a vector field i.e it has different values of velocity at different points in space. That is why you get different components at different points.

Rate of change of $x-component$ of velocity in the x- direction is $\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}$. Now since the centre of parallelopiped is $\frac{dx}{2}$ units away from the centres of faces of parallelopiped, we multiply by $\frac{dx}{2} $ to obtain change in velocity.

Using the same logic, since the centre of face 1 is $\frac{dx}{2}$ away from the centre of parallelopiped, we subtract the change in velocity from the velocity at the centre.

Comment: So,according to your 3rd paragraph, the velocity $V_x$ is changing at a constant rate as ths velocity at face 1 is find out by  $V_x-\frac{1}{2}\frac {\partial V_x}{x}dx$.