Maxwell's third equation for static fields


Since electrostatic field lines are bending why it's curl is zero
specifically asking about charge distribution with bending field lines (example - Dipole)
Please explain with physical meaning not mathematical

Notice that reference to a local rotation of the vector field is meaningful, reference to angular momentum is, in general, misleading. For example, even though a static magnetic field may have a non-zero curl (in the presence of a non-zero current density), there is no angular momentum in the absence of an electric field.

This question is similar to: What is the physical significance of curl $\nabla\times\boldsymbol{V}$?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202923/174766 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/533880/174766

Curl is defined at a point in space, not over an extended volume/area.
The usual analogy used is to imagine the field lines as field lines of fluid velocity and to consider a tiny paddle wheel dropped into the field lines and to ask whether that paddle wheel rotates with respect to tbe fluid flow lines as it is carried along. If it does not, then the curl is zero.
Unfortunately, although it is obvious in some cases whether curl is present or not, in others, like the one you show, it is difficult to tell (without maths).
Perhaps the classic example is to imagine circular, closed field lines, circulating around the z-axis. If the field lines are equally spaced, the field has positive curl. If they gradually get further apart, to represent a field diminishing as $1/r$, there is no curl. If instead the field strength diminishes as $1/r^2$, there is negative curl. All with circular field lines.
In the middle case, one can imagine the area tiled with small pseudo-squares. I say pseudo-squares, because to get them to tesselate, the sides perpendicular to the field lines are straight, but not quite parallel, but the sides parallel to the flow are slightly curved and the outer side (at larger $r$) needs to be longer than the inner side. If you take a closed line integral around this loop, the sides perpendicular to the flow make no contribution. The sides parallel to the field make an equal but opposite contribution because whilst the outer side is longer (proportional to $r$), the field strength is weaker (by $1/r$) and their product is constant.
The same thing works for the field you have shown. You will notice that where there is curvature of the field lines, the lines are more closely spaced (the field is stronger) on the inside of the curve. That ensures that the closed line integral of the field is zero.

Let me try and add an intuitive way of understanding curl.
Suppose we take a point and draw a loop round that point. Then we can take that loop to be the border of a small area $d\mathbf{A}$. Now we integrate the field round the loop and divide it by the magnitude of the area and the result is approximately the curl at that point.

I've used the term approximate because to get the curl at a point we need to take a loop centred at that point and let the radius of the loop shrink to zero. Then the curl of the field at that point is the limit we get as $r\to0$.
As a rough guide a field has a non-zero curl when the field lines form loops. This is why a non-zero curl is associated with a non-conservative field i.e. the integral round a loop is non-zero meaning the associated potential is path dependent.
This is what Allure's answer refers to. Suppose you take the field lines I have coloured green and integrate round that loop:

Round the left half you're going with the field and round the right half you're going against the loop, so the two halves cancel and the integral round the loop is going to be zero. It's not obvious this will be true for any possible loop you can draw, and indeed it can be hard to tell if a field has a zero or non-zero curl just be looking at it - unless you're lucky and you can see an obvious loop. The only safe way to tell is to calculate the curl.

"A vector field has a non-zero curl when the field lines form loops. " disproved by the magnetic field from a long wire.

Because it's symmetric. The "positive curl" from one side is balanced by the "negative curl" on the other side. In the same way if you spin your left hand clockwise and your right hand anti-clockwise, your net angular momentum is zero, even though individual parts are rotating.

I think something should be added to your explanation. Curl is a local quantity (curl at a point), while your argument uses a non-local argument (one side,  ... the other side). I am afraid that OP's request to avoid math is excessive in this case.

In electrostatics, the curl of the electric field is represents (negative) magnetic charge current. Since there are no observed magnetic charges, it is set to zero. For the AI response, it is not accurate. If you were to imagine the electric field as the velocity field of an imaginary fluid, its curl would represent (twice) the local, instantaneous angular velocity (not angular momentum!) of an infinitesimally small parcel of fluid carried by the flow. It is really not obvious from the dipole field, because the shape of the field lines is not enough to deduce it. The value of the field strength matter, and you will have to do the math to check it out.
